# How to define a variable within a function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error that says at line 27, total is undefined. To fix this previously I added global to lines 7 and 12 so I tried adding it at line 17 and it is still giving me an error. Any idea how I can fix this? Any other tips or info regarding my code is greatly appreciated as well. I'm very new to coding. I'm working in Python

```
import math
import sys
print("King's BMI Calculator")


def h():
    global height
    height=float(input("Please enter student's height in inches:"))
    return height

def w():
    global weight
    weight=float(input("Please enter student's weight in pounds:"))
    return weight

def bmi():
    global total
    total=((str(weight) * 703)/(str(height) * str(height)))
    return total

def printbmi():
    print(name + "'s BMI Profile")
    print("Height:", str(height), "inches")
    print("Weight:", str(weight), "lbs")
    print("BMI Index:" + str(float(round(total, 1))))
    return

def main():
    h()
    w()
    printbmi()

while True:
    name = input("Please enter student's name or press 0 to quit:")
    if name == "0":
        break

    main()
```

Comment: Help us out, here. What's line 27?

Comment: oh, sorry about that. my line numbers are all messed up anyway...

Comment: the error is at ...   print("BMI Index:" + str(float(round(total, 1))))
NameError: name 'total' is not defined

Comment: Also, you probably mean `int(height)` and not `str(height)`, etc. User input is a string. Math requires an `int()` or a `float()`, not a `str()`.

Comment: @Austin Hastings  when it said that height and weight were not defined, i just went up to the functions and added global height and global weight. not sure if that's the correct way, but it fixed the error

Comment: @AustinHastings Thank you, I see what you mean about int() instead of str() but i still get the error saying total is not defined

Comment: Call bmi(), somewhere before printbmi().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `global` when you are modifying a global variable. You don't have to use it when you are just reading the variable, as long as the variable is defined.

In this case, you don't define total anywhere, because your code calls `w` and `h()` and `printbmi()` but doesn't appear to call `bmi()`, which is the only place you store a value to `total.`